# Can I query Microsoft GP database and save the result as MDF file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamics-gp

I have a request as below for auditing purpose on Microsoft Dynamic GP database.

1. Database files are required as `.mdf` and `.ldf` files for certain companies
2. Only need the certain period time of data, not entire database from day 1 till now

My questions:

1. Is this even possible to provide only certain period time of activities from database as `.mdf` file? I mean if the `.mdf` file is required, it must be the entire database right?
2. If it is possible, how? Query the database for everything happened in that period of time and save it as `.mdf` file and `.ldf` file? Or somehow somewhat cut the `.mdf` file? I don't think so...
3. or if I provide entire database with only that period of transaction log?

Comment: Whoever asked you to do this should feel bad about themselves (I assume it's some government entity). This is not possible in any kind of way that I would consider a good practice. We're talking accounting information. You can't just divvy up the database by some arbitrary date values. How would you even begin to do that? You would have to recreate a new database and only import the transactions from a specific date period. And how would that be certified as valid data by a CPA? Push back on this as hard as you can!

Comment: lol, it was government asking for this

Comment: I reposted this  question on "Database Admin". so close this one

Comment: Looks like they gave you a similar answer to mine. The problem is, whoever asked for this just doesn't understand how databases work. My recommendation is still to push back and figure out why you are being asked to do this ridiculous task!